# How to expose the quantity of list items to an action?

Tags: rules

Put another way.

Using a **loop**, how do I pass the number of items in a list to an **action** outside the **loop**?

I have created a loop and within the loop I have added an action to calculate a data value as follows

```
Data selector: 'loop_name:quantity' 

Calculation: *1 = calculation_result
```

From within the loop I can access the new variable '`calculation_result`' however I can not figure out how to expose the calculation result to other data selectors.

What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new variable BEFORE your loop.

[image: Select add a variable from rules action]

And then select the type of variables in that list. For your example, perhaps a list of decimals?

[image: Select a list of decimals]

Be sure to give it a good custom name for your loop:

[image: Give the variable a good custom name]

Then, in your loop, you can add a new variable to an existing list:

[image: Add an item to a list]

Then, after your loop, you can access calculation results:

[image: Select from a list]

Note, that if you don't know explicitly which in your loop you want, then you will have to loop through your new calculation results and use a condition rule to return the one you need as (yet another) variable.

Comment: Thank you for this most comprehensive answer. It must have taken you ages

Comment: @MrPaulDriver yet you never accepted his answer by clicking the checkmark, nor voted him up so he gets reputation points (-_-)